# NuGetter: How to specify nuspec files to generate multiple packages in a single build definition?

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild

I am trying to generate **multiple nuget packages** using the TFS NuGetter. I am using the NuGetterMultiPkgBuildVersionedTemplate20.xaml for this. I can generate one package successfully but am having trouble in specifying multiple nuspec files.

Using the following definition sample from http://nugetter.codeplex.com/ I can successfully generate one package.

[image]

How can I specify multiple nuspec files so that it generates multiple nuget packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple package list needs to be provided in a separate file and file needs to be mentioned in the following section in **NuGetterMultiPkgBuildVersionedTemplate20.xaml**

**6. NuGetter (A) - PrePackaging

Multi-package List File Path -> NuGetPrePackage\AppMultiPackages.xml**

Format of the file can be like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NuGetterPackages>
    <NuGetterPackage name="Sample1">
        <NuSpecFilePath>NuGetPrePackage\Sample1.nuspec</NuSpecFilePath>
        <BasePath>NuGetPrePackage</BasePath>
        <InvokePowerShell>True</InvokePowerShell>
        <PowerShellScriptPath>Powershell\Sample1\PrePackage.ps1</PowerShellScriptPath>
        <InvokePush>True</InvokePush>
        <OutputDirectory>NuGetPackage</OutputDirectory>
        <PushDestination>D:\Drops\PackageRepository\MySite\Test</PushDestination>
        <Version>4.0.j.b</Version>
    </NuGetterPackage>  
    <NuGetterPackage name="Sample2">
        <NuSpecFilePath>NuGetPrePackage\Sample2.nuspec</NuSpecFilePath>
        <BasePath>NuGetPrePackage</BasePath>
        <InvokePowerShell>True</InvokePowerShell>
        <PowerShellScriptPath>Powershell\Sample2\PrePackage.ps1</PowerShellScriptPath>
        <InvokePush>True</InvokePush>
        <OutputDirectory>NuGetPackage</OutputDirectory>
        <PushDestination>D:\Drops\PackageRepository\MySite\Test</PushDestination>
        <Version>4.2.j.b</Version>
    </NuGetterPackage>  
</NuGetterPackages>
```

Following screenshot from the documentation explains different options nicely.

[image]